# Disjoint sets data structures and binomial trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, disjoint-sets, binomial-heap

Can someone either explain what Disjoint Sets Data Structure is?, or alternatively link me to a YouTube video or article that explains it well.

I searched for it a few minutes ago and all I got were some Math lessons that involved an image that looked like a venn diagram. Maybe that is it, but I am not sure, so any help is appreciated.

On a quick side note, when I am asked "How to use binary tree to represent each binomial tree in a binomial queue" Is this referring to the binomial trees that you have to stack upon one another. Like B1 attaches with a B1 to become a B2, then two B2's become a B3, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disjoint set data structures are data structures for representing a [partition of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) S.  You begin with a set S of elements, each of which belongs to its own group.  For example:

```
{1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}
```

One operation on a disjoint-set data structure is the **union** operation, which combines together the two sets containing the given elements.  For example, unioning together 1 and 2 gives back the partition

```
{1, 2} {3} {4} {5} {6}
```

Unioning together 3 and 5 produces

```
{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}, {6}
```

Now, unioning together 1 and 3 produces the partition

```
{1, 2, 3, 5}, {4}, {6}
```

The **find** operation tells you which set a given element belongs to.  Typically, this is done by having find return a representative element of the element it belongs to.  This is usually done such that

```
find(x) == find(y)  if and only if  x and y are in the same set.
```

For example, find(1) might return 2, and so find(2) = 2, find(3) = 2, find(5) = 2.

Disjoint set data structures are often used as a subroutine in Kruskal's minimum spanning tree algorithm, as they provide a very fast way of checking whether two nodes in the graph are connected and an easy way of marking that all nodes in two connected components are connected to one another when an edge is added.  Using the **[disjoint-set forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests)** implementation with union-by-rank and path compression, n operations on a disjoint-set forest can be done in O(n α(n)) time, where α(n) is the [*inverse Ackermann function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse), a function that grows so slowly it's effectively a constant (it's at most four for any input less than the size of the universe.)

---

As for binomial trees and binary trees: I think what you are asking about is how to represent binomial trees, which are many-way trees, using binary trees, which have at most two children.  Not all binomial trees are binary trees, so a suitable encoding must be used.

One way to do this is using something called the [**left-child right-sibling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) representation.  This represents a many-way tree as a binary tree according to the following setup:

- The **left** child of each node points to the node's first child.
- The **right** child of each node points to its next sibling (node in the same layer with the same parent).

For example, given this binomial tree:

```
     a
   / | \
  b  c  d
 /|  |
e f  g
  |
  h
```

The left-child right-sibling representation would be

```
                 a
                /
               b
            /    \
           e      c
            \    / \
             f  g   d
            /
           h
```

By the way - if you do this on binomial trees, you end up with a representation of a binomial tree as something called a **half-ordered half-tree**, which is a binary tree with the following properties:

- Every node in the tree is greater than or equal to (or less than or equal to, depending on whether this is a min-heap or a max-heap) every node in its left subtree.
- The root node has no right child.

These definitions follow from the fact that a binomial tree is heap-ordered and then converted into a left-child right-sibling representation.  Using this representation, it is extremely fast to link together to binomial trees.  I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I get most of this and it is coming back to me now. Question though, Can you explain to me or point me to a resource on how to built the left-child right-sibling representation. I think I am missing a step in there and my brain slightly fried right now too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Disjoint set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is basically a union-find Data Structure.

You originally have a set of `n` nodes, and you have **`find(node)`** and **`union(node1,node2)`** operations on it.

- `union(node1,node2)` is making "combining" the nodes to be in one set
- `find(node)` is finding the canonic representation of `node` (by
  giving the root, for example, as later explained)

For example, you originally have `{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}`, and you do:

```
union(1,2)
union(3,4)
```

Then you end up having `{1,2},{3,4},{5}`.

This also means that at this point `find(1) == find(2)` (It is the same set!)

If you later `union(2,3)` - it will result in unioning the *set* containing 2 with the *set* containing 3, and you will end up with `{1,2,3,4},{5}`

**Regarding a video request**: [This lecture from Berkley](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSPAjGfDl7Q) seems to cover the material pretty well.

---

Regarding binary trees - it is one way of implementation, each "root" has its sons, but the tree is actually "upside down", instead of having pointers from father to sons, you have pointers from sons to father.

This way, the canon representation of each node is the root the node leads up to, and this ensures us that if we did union on `a` and `b` - then `find(a) = find(b)`, because they have the same root.

I hope it gives you some leads on what this DS is.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The disjoint sets I learned at uni revolved around three essential functions.

```
make_set(x) - makes a new disjoint contains only the element x
find_set(x) - gives you the set that contains element x
union(x,y) - unions the sets that contain x and y
```

The implementation they mentioned was with linked lists. That is each set has the a representative of the element that created the set. (`make_set(x)`) and then with `unions(x,y)`, the end pointer of `x` is moved to point to `y`. `Union` and `make_set` are fast but this was pretty slow for `find_set` (in fact O(biggest set))

The better implementation used two methods called *path compression*, which as an element was passed by with `union` and/or `find_set`, it made it point to the representative of the set

The other, *union-by-rank*, which maintained a rank for each set that gave the greatest 'depth' of the set. When unioned, if the rank of each set was the same, it added one to the rank and one representative was changed to point to the other. If they were different, then the smaller set was changed to point to the representative of the larger and the rank is left unchanged. This asymptotic upper bound of this is really close to just the number of uses of the functions.

Hope that helps.